# Unity Jump if touch ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Upon left clicking, the Player should jump if the condition of colliding with the "Ground" layer is true.

Problem: when I click it is not making the jump.

Hierarchy(3)

- **Main Camera**
- **Player**
- **Floor**

Inspector info:
[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public float jumpForce = 25f;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;
    
    void Awake()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();    
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Jump();
        }
    }
    
    void Jump(){
    
        if (IsGrounded()) {
            rigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
        
     
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    
    bool IsGrounded()
    {
        if (Physics2D.Raycast(this.transform.position, Vector2.down, 0.2f, groundLayer.value)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see how big your player is but make sure the raycast can actually reach the floor since it's only 0.2 meters long. You can use `Debug.DrawLine()` to see the raycast in the editor.

Also make sure the jump force value is high enough.

Comment: Yes, the raycast, was not reaching the floor, thus not capable of applying the conditional statement.